# Please review and consider re-opening my post

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I have updated my SE post and I have no idea how to re-open it and have no feedback from my updates, it's very frustrating.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386361/angular-js-integration-with-phpbb3

Please review this post.

Comment: No, that question is way too broad. Find a very specific problem and ask a question on that instead.

Answer (score 4):

It reads too broadly to me.

I've had limited exposure to both Angular and PHP, so I'm familiar with the technologies.  Ultimately, your question boils down to:

> How can I use Angular and phpBB3 together?

There are *a lot* of ways to approach this, which makes it "too broad".  Having a [quick skim of their forums](https://area51.phpbb.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=45283) also indicates that they'd need a new version (likely 3.2+) to make it work properly, as well as they'd want to ensure that it doesn't conflict with the existing jQuery support.

A little bit of research done here proved out that it's not wholly supported by the backend, so any solution you get would be incomplete at best.

Comment: And while I keep adding updates to narrow it down, I get absolutely no feedback.  I have also done a heap of investigation into this and just don't know what is involved.  I have attempted to solve this myself.  If my solution can't work, then so be it, but at least a discussion about this will help, and the discussion will never happen while the post is closed.  Which is sooo frustrating.

Comment: The feedback is honestly that the question is too broad to consider answering.  Doing something like adding Angular to phpBB3 isn't something that's trivial, it requires a lot of work and effort to make it work, and work reliably.  That's not a question that any of us could answer; we're just volunteering what precious leisure time we have here.

Comment: I want to integrate a phpbb forum into my site, so it navigates seamless. I have no idea how to do this, but I have to start somewhere.

Comment: Start by researching on the official phpBB site.  See if there's been anyone that's at least discussed it and see what they've attempted.  If you really are hard on using Angular to support your forum frontend, then look to see if there are any other forum solutions that can support your requests, or roll your own.

Comment: Would posting on this subject in the stack meta be a better way to have a discussion on the subject perhaps?  I'd like feedback or suggestions on this question and I'm just not getting anything on stack overflow, which is actually really unhelpful and is counter productive.

Comment: Not to mention, i'm getting lots of negative feedback votes for my posts, which is also a frustration when you don't know what you are doing wrong.  Thank you for your help btw, it is appreciated.

Comment: @Craig no, neither SO nor Meta is an appropriate place for discussing whether/how it's possible to do what you want. You may see this as *"really unhelpful"* and *"counter productive"* but SO isn't (can't be!) the home for every question. You might find some like-minded souls in a relevant chat, but otherwise you'll have to try outside this network.